# how to get the dropdown selected value and send it to controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

am having the following code

view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $("#Login").click(function() 
                {   
                    $("#message").html("");
                    var action = $("#loginform").attr('action');
                    var login_data = {
                        username: $("#txt_email").val(),
                        password: $("#txt_password").val(),
                        language: $("#language").val(),
                        is_ajax: 1
                    };
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/login',
                        data: login_data,
                        success: function(response)
                        {   
                            if(response == 'success')  
                            {
                                $("#message").html("<span class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</span><p>Redirecting...</p>");
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/communication_letter';
                                }, 2000);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                $("#message").html("<span class='error'>OOPS! Authentication failed</span>");   
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id= "header">
    <br/>
            <p style="text-align:center; color:#8D0F1D;font-size:28px" >Work Environment Survey</p>

     </div>
    <div id= "bar" style="z-index:1">
     <div id="logo" style="z-index:2">

     </div>


     </div>
     <br/>
    <br/>


     <div id="homemain">

        <!--div id="content-login"-->
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <form action="#" id="loginform" method="post">
                    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email Id </td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txt_email" name="username"  /></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password </td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="txt_password" name="password" /></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Select Language</td>
                            <td><select style="width:215px" name="language" id = "language" ><option value="simplified">English with Simplified Chinese</option>
                            <option value="traditional">English with Traditional Chinese</option>
                            </select></td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="image" id="Login" style="position:relative;left:120px" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/login.png"/>
                </form>
```

and the controller is as follows

```
public function login()
    {   
        if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax']) {
            $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
            $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
            echo $verify = $this->user_model->user_login($username, $password);
            exit;
        }
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
```

here how can i get the dropdown selected value depending on the language selected i need to open the next page. please someone help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can get that by using `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` like you did for username

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax']) {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $language= $_REQUEST['language'];

        echo $verify = $this->user_model->user_login($username, $password);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: how to view whether $language is getting data or not

Comment: check with if condition.. `if($language)`

Comment: in view page? i gave as follows  $("#message").html("<span class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</span><p>Redirecting...</p>");
        setTimeout(function() {
        <?php // print_r($language);exit;?>
        if($language == simplified){
        
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/communication_letter';
        }
        else{
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/trad_communication_letter';
        }
        }, 2000); but it is not working it is not opening any page it is standing in login itself

Comment: public function login()
 { 
  if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax']) {
   $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
   $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
   $language= $_REQUEST['language'];
   echo $verify = $this->user_model->user_login($username, $password, $language);
   exit;
  }
  $this->load->view('login');
 } if am giving in this way itself it is showing authentication failed f am removing language then it is working fine. what is the wrong am doing can someone correct it please.

Comment: check what are you getting in language `echo $language`

Comment: if am giving echo $language in controller it is shoeing error as authentication failed

Comment: i found solution to my problem thanks to everyone who tried to help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want, when user enter correct credential, user will be redirected to the page depending on the language selected by the user. You do not need to access language in your controller because you are redirecting from you login page,

you controller has to be

```
public function login()
{   
    if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax']) {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $verify = $this->user_model->user_login($username, $password);
        if($verify){
          echo 1;
        }else{
           echo 0;
        }
    }
}
```

you don't need to load view, as it is an ajax response.

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/login',
                    data: login_data,
                    success: function(response)
                    {   
                        if(response == 1)  
                        {
                            $("#message").html("<span class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</span><p>Redirecting...</p>");
                            setTimeout(function() {
                             if($("#language").val() == "simplified"){
                          window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/communication_letter';
                             }else{
                           window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>survey/trad_communication_letter'; }
                             }
                            }, 2000);
                         }
                        else 
                        {
                            $("#message").html("<span class='error'>OOPS! Authentication failed</span>");   
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I hope this will help you.  please check you development tool (chrome) or firebug (firefox) that your request is going and what is coming in response.

Comment: can you please share you model?, and what is in the response variable?

Comment: function validate_login($username, $password) {
  $encryptedPass = base64_encode(md5($password));
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('email_id', $username);
  $this->db->where('password', $encryptedPass);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $login = $query->num_rows();
  if ($login) {$getId = $query->result();
   $userId = $getId[0]->admin_user_id;
   $username = $getId[0]->email_id;
   $sessionData = array(
      'email_id'  => $username,
      'user_id' => $userId,
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
   return 'success';}
  return 'failed';

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to grab the selected index value from drop down is

```
$('#language option:selected').val();
```

also in your controller you can verify the ajax request using

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```